# What is midnight commander option "dive in to subdir if exists" copy option for?

Tags: linux, mc

When I press F5 it has one of the options to **dive in to subdir if exists** but what does that actually mean?

You'd think it means if you copy without that option it would copy just one level, but without that option it copies the entire tree.  Which is why I wonder what the option is for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this option enabled a source directory will be copied/moved into a new subdirectory if a target directory of the same name already exists.

e.g.

You are copying a folder DATA with files to a location that already has a DATA folder. With this option enabled mc will put the source DATA folder into the existing DATA folder, so the new data is now in DATA/DATA.

The option is badly worded since a lot of people think about it as a "recursive" option, thinking it applies to source directories, but the "subdir" is in the target location.

I just learned about this too after years of using mc.